# Open-Source Web Analytics using Cassandra?

Tags: java, cassandra, analytics, web-analytics

Does anyone know of any open source web analytics tools or examples that make use of Cassandra as the datastore?  I'd prefer something written in Java, but would be interested in taking a look at any projects with this setup as a learning exercise.

Comment: Did you try open web analytics or piwik or spagobi?